# Using the same column in partition by and order by with DENSE_RANK()

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I am using `DENSE_RANK()` function, I have used the same column in the partition by clause and order by clause. The Dense_rank result for all rows is 1. Why it happened like this?

**Table :**

```
orderid custid  
10643    1
10692    1
10702    1
10308    2
10625    2
10759    2
10926    2 
10365    3
10507    3
10535    3
10573    3
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT orderid, custid ,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition BY custid ORDER BY custid) as desnse_rank
FROM TABLE
```

**The Result**

```
orderid custid  desnse_rank          
10643    1        1                  
10692    1        1                    
10702    1        1                     
10308    2        1                  
10625    2        1                  
10759    2        1                   
10926    2        1                    
10365    3        1                    
10507    3        1                  
10535    3        1                   
10573    3        1
```

**Expected Result** (as my understand of `dense_rank()`):

```
orderid custid  desnse_rank  
10643    1        1
10692    1        1   
10702    1        1  
10308    2        2
10625    2        2
10759    2        2
10926    2        2
10365    3        3 
10507    3        3
10535    3        3
10573    3        3
```

Comment: You can but It's meaningless. `Partition by` means that all the records in a partition will have the same value for the `partition by` columns. What do you want to rank? The expected results you posted don't show any ranking, they just repeat the `custid` value

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in partitioning by a column and ordering by the same column, as each partition will always have the same column value to order.

What you need is to avoid the partition. The columns at the `PARTITION BY` will tell the ranking when to reset back to 1 and start the ranking again, that is when the referenced column changes value. For your attempt, when `custid` changes value from 1 to 2, another partition kicks in and the dense rank starts again from 1, this is why you get 1 for all you rows.

This will give your desired outcome (just 1 partition!).

```
SELECT orderid, custid , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY custid) as dense_rank FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `order by`

```
select orderid,custid
,DENSE_RANK() over (order by custid) rn 
from @tabel
```